# following several unknown phenomena detected at the edge of the solar system, is there a 5th force which acts at the edge of the solar system?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, cosmology, asteroids

following several unknown phenomena detected as the acceleration of Oumuamua and electrons and strange data sent by traveler 1 at the edge of the solar system, is there a 5th force which acts at the edge of the solar system?

Sorry the source is in French I don't speak English.

Source that electrons accelerated at solar system without explanation at the edge of the solar system:

[Sondes Voyager : hors du Système solaire, elles découvrent un nouveau phénomène](https://news.knowledia.com/CH/fr/articles/sondes-voyager-hors-du-systeme-solaire-elles-decouvrent-un-nouveau-71df6b7d6b93c0187103a1f087f16fed421abf3b)

Source that the asteroid Oumuamua accelerates without explanation at the edge of the solar system:

[Astéroïde Oumuamua : l'hypothèse extraterrestre relancée](https://www.sciencesetavenir.fr/espace/univers/oumuamua-l-hypothese-extraterrestre-relancee_129244)

Source that voyager 1 sends data abroad from the edge of the solar system:

[La NASA reçoit d’étranges données provenant de la sonde Voyager 1](https://trustmyscience.com/nasa-recoit-etranges-donnees-provenant-sonde-voyager-1/)

Answer (score 6):

I've reviewed your sources, but I don't think they make the claims you say they do.  The first relates to interactions between solar wind electrons and cosmic rays.  This interaction is complex and not fully understood, but I don't see a claim or need for new fundamental physics.

The second relates to a rather speculative paper that Oumuanmua may be a spacecraft.  The paper was rather soundly criticised. Again I don't see a claim or need for new fundamental physics.

The third relates to anomalies in articulation and attitude control system.  Again, I don't see a claim of anomalous acceleration that would require the existence of a fifth force.

I may be misunderstanding the google translations. A "fifth force" would be a remarkable discovery (easily worth a Nobel prize). At the moment, there isn't the data that needs to be explained by it.

Comment: the connection between all its phenomena is that they are unknown and until today are without explanation, in any case it is observed that small or large objects accelerate or edge of the solar system without explanation, and that the data of the traveler 1 are strange, I am waiting for traveler 2 to pass in the same limit and there would be no doubt if he sends the same data as traveler 1,

Comment: in addition there is another phenomenon detected, the disturbance of the trajectories of the planets next to the edge of the solar system, it has even been proposed that there is a planet 9 but we have never found it, so I think that all its phenomena are rather linked to a force 5 which acts at the edge of the solar system...

Comment: @newuser10 Those are just things that we have insufficient data and models for, but have no reason to suspect are obeying or observably subject to anything other than the laws and forces of physics we already know of. Having a bunch of things we need more data and better models for is a hallmark of science; we'd have nothing to science if such a problem didn't exist!

Comment: @Timmy zibadawa In physics in general when we reach a certain limit there is always a saturation effect which does not behave like the normal state without saturation and its observations  even if there is not much data they show that there is to something strange happening at the edge of the solar system, in any case if voyager 2 passes this limit and provides the same data as traveler 1 all our knowledge in physics would have to be updated and even a force 5 would be possible to explain all his observations...